# Type error when drawing chart - Google Charts & Fusion Tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

I've been bashing my head against this for a little too long now - probably to the point of missing something completely obvious.

I am trying to generate a bar chart showing the number of public toilets per state from this Fusion Table - https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Acf5-fZ1fbRrbsCthOSu2q5s0PmMFBVFI8tuCg - obviously there isn't anything that easily counts this for me so I'm having to do it through the query.

This is the code I have so far...

```
var dataURL = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=';
var query = "SELECT state, COUNT() " +
"FROM 1Acf5-fZ1fbRrbsCthOSu2q5s0PmMFBVFI8tuCg GROUP BY state";
var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
gvizQuery.send(function(response) {
    if(response.isError()){
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    data = response.getDataTable();
//This bit below is to see what I'm getting in the data table   
for(i in data){
        document.getElementById('visualization').innerHTML += data[i];
    }
var chart = google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
var options = {
    title: 'Toilets by State',
    vAxis: {title: 'State',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
    };
chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

When I try to run it, I get "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'thispc')" from format+en,default,corechart.I.js:824 - which I cannot pin down. When I pump out the data table to the page, I get the usual series of [object Object] with a chunk of Javascript after it - which looks odd to me.

Any suggestions - or glaring errors that anyone can see?

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables can do the aggregation for you, like so: 
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S568510O6Lf

Then Visualize > Bar and "Get embeddable link" for:

Or, use the aggregation (GROUP BY) query via the gviz API ([sample code](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#gviz)) for more control.

-Rebecca